# ASP.NET how to access AspNetUsers table and return values

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Successfully I added some fields in AspNetUsers  table but I don't know how I can retrieve them. My project is asp.net web api and I can retrieve username from token. I want to return departmentId by given userId, or username.
and trying like but this gives me null exeption

```
   private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;


        public int GetdeptId(string username)
        {
           var dept =  _userManager.Users.Where(d => d.UserName == username).Select(c => c.DepartmentId).FirstOrDefault();
            return dept;


        }
```

Here is the way I could create fields in my AspNetUsers and I can insert values successfully. The problem is to return values from AspNetUsers.

```
public class RegisterBindingModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Lastname")]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

And then the registerration

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Firstname = model.FirstName, LastName =        model.Lastname, DepartmentId = model.DepartmentId };

            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                return GetErrorResult(result);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are using the default ASP.NET project template, you should have a class called `ApplicationUserManager`, in UserManager you can find lots of `FindBy` methods that you can use... `FindByNameAsync` might fits your needs here.

Comment: @RosdiKasim thank you for response, but please show me how to do that.. I'am new to this staffs ....how can I formulate the code? I have no idea how to code it. Thank you again

Comment: @RosdiKasim Hi there, I have edited my code but I get null exception

Answer (score 1):

Try!

var context = new IdentityDbContext();

var users = context.Users.ToList();

Answer (score -1):

If you have access to your ApplicationDbContext as say, _db, then you can cast it to IdentityDbContext and access the tables through that. e.g.
`IdentityDbContext context = _db as IdentityDbContext;`
`IEnumerable<User> users = context.Users;`